# How to use MySQL MATCH AGAINST IN BOOLEAN MODE to return results for at least 1 matching keyword inside a keywords string?

Tags: php, mysql, boolean, mode, match-against

I have this query for searching database entries based on keywords entered on a search box.

```
// function to get search keywords from url
$q = furl($_GET['q']);

$sExp = preg_split('/\s+/',$q); 
$secure_keywords = array(); 
foreach ($sExp as $key=>$keyword){
    if (strlen($keyword) >= 3){ 
    // cut off words that are less than 3 chars
    $secure_keywords[] = $keyword;
    }
}
$kwords = count($secure_keywords); 
foreach ($secure_keywords as $key=>$keyword) 
{ 
// function to prevent sql injection
$keyword = sql_proof($keyword); 

$query="SELECT * FROM listings WHERE MATCH (meta_keywords) AGAINST ('$keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY id"; 
}
```

When 2 or more words are used, if at least 1 word is misspelled then the query will not return any results (even if results do exist for the rest of the words in the keywords entered). For example, I enter the word "good" and I get at least 1 result, but if I use "good point" the query doesn't return any results, so it totally ignores the matching results for the word "good".
Is there a way for the query to match results if there is at least 1 matching word in the keywords entered? Thanks

Comment: Please, provide your _actual_ SQL query (after all substitutions) and sample of data in table with expected results and actual results

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using 'In boolean mode' try

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE MATCH (title, body) AGAINST ('database test')
```

It returns result even if you have no word like 'test' after database

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE MATCH (col1, col2) AGAINST ('string to be searched')
```

Comment: I tried this already but I get a white page if IN BOOLEAN MODE is removed. Any other suggestion? Thanks

Comment: did you tried AGAINST('database' WITH QUERY EXPANSION) instead of Boolean mode

Comment: Yes, same result as before when I removed IN BOOLEAN MODE.

Comment: Please post query you are using

Comment: SELECT * FROM `listings` WHERE MATCH (meta_keywords) AGAINST ('$keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY id

Comment: try using a static variable in the query instead of $keyword to check if its working, there can be issues with the data in the variable.

Comment: see the variable u are using in query is keyword, and it is defined in for each so its value is not stored, its a kind of alias. if possible add more code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it looks like that's the problem. More code follows

Comment: $q = furl($_GET['q']);
        $sExp = preg_split('/\s+/',$q);
 $secure_keywords = array();
 foreach ($sExp as $key=>$keyword)
        {
  if (strlen($keyword) >= 3)
                { // cut off words that are less than 3 chars
$secure_keywords[] = $keyword;
  }
 }
        $kwords = count($secure_keywords);
 foreach ($secure_keywords as $key=>$keyword)
        {
  $keyword = sql_proof($keyword);

    $query="SELECT * FROM listings WHERE MATCH (meta_keywords) AGAINST ('$keyword' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY id";
         }

Any ideas what might be wrong in my $keyword variable?

Comment: what does furl, sql_proof function do. and what kind of data will $q have

Comment: furl is used to find the q variable which holds the keywords in the url. sql_proof is to protect the input by sql injection. I removed the sql_proof function but I get the same result so I don't think that would be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the below solution for a way to match the results against ANY of the keywords used. Also check the docs for more info on operators and boolean fst http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html

```
// function to get search keywords from url
$q = furl($_GET['q']);

$sExp = preg_split('/\s+/',$q); 
$secure_keywords = array(); 
foreach ($sExp as $key=>$keyword){
    if (strlen($keyword) >= 3){ 
    // cut off words that are less than 3 chars
    $secure_keywords[] = $keyword;
    }
}
$kwords = count($secure_keywords); 

//init empty keywords array
$keywords = array();

//secure all keywords
$keywords = array_map(function($item){ return sql_proof($item); }, $secure_keywords); 

//implode the words with a space between
$keywords = implode(" ",$keywords);

//just one query with match against ANY of the words from initial keyword array
$query="SELECT * FROM listings WHERE MATCH (meta_keywords) AGAINST ('$keywords' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY id";
```